# How to add data that separated with comas to database

Tags: php, mysql, implode

i want to insert my data to database. i have data that separated with commas.

for example i have data like this:

```
$rand_post = ["3001182708", "3001182713", "3001183215"]; 
$id_post = '123456';
```

here is the best answer i get after searching in internet

```
$prep = array();
foreach($rand_post as $k => $v ) {
    $prep[':'.$k] = $v;
}
print_r($prep);
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tes (`datas`) VALUES (" . implode('), (',array_keys($prep)) . ")");
$res = $sth->execute($prep);
```

but it just insert data for `$rand_post`

i want to insert my data like this

```
id_post            rand_post
============       ================
123456             3001182708
123456             3001182713
123456             3001183215
```

after try answer from splash

```
id_post            rand_post
============       ================
123456             2147483647
123456             2147483647
123456             2147483647
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make pairs in the loop

```
$prep = array();
foreach($rand_post as $v ) {
    $prep[] = "($id_post, $v)";
}
print_r($prep);
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tes (`id_post`,`datas`) VALUES " . implode(', ', $prep));
// INSERT INTO tes (`id_post`,`datas`) VALUES (123456, 3001182708), (123456, 3001182713), (123456, 3001183215)
$res = $sth->execute($prep);
```

Comment: i got this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\ainodorama\jy-adm\tes.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ainodorama\jy-adm\tes.php on line 13

Comment: @Jazuly get it now, i lost `$db->prepare`

Comment: it record same value from $rand_post, when i try it just record `2147483647` and looping it for 3 times.

Comment: `2147483647` even not my datas. i dont even know from where its.

Comment: As you can see, the code gets values from variables $rand_post and $id_post

Comment: check my question, i show the result after i run u code.

Comment: @splash58 i think u forget `(` after `VALUES`

Comment: @Jazuly - sorry, my mistake, not awake yet :-/